# Logical operator ignored in Postgres command

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, logical-operators

I have a left join command that also checks for matching letters and two other combinctions in the data between the joined tables. The DISTINCT ON is to ensure the location_plus has no duplication as results from the table on the right. To test my results I added an AND to check for a particular account numbers results. This AND component seems to be completely ignored, returning almost all of the records instead of the ~10 for that a/c number. Why is this?

```
SELECT
DISTINCT ON (location_plus)
a.*,b.*
FROM schema.source_table b
LEFT JOIN schema.other_reference a
ON a.loc_id = (substring(b.loc_id,3))::integer
WHERE left(b.loc_id,1)=left(a.table_name,1)
OR ((left(b.loc_id,1)='B' AND left(a.table_name,1)='A') OR (left(b.loc_id,1)='B' AND left(a.table_name,1)='B'))
and b.account_number='12345678'
```

Comment: Because you are mixing `OR` with `AND` without proper parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND` has precendence over `OR`. So

```
WHERE left(b.loc_id,1)=left(a.table_name,1)
OR (...) 
and b.account_number='12345678'
```

is

```
WHERE left(b.loc_id,1)=left(a.table_name,1)
OR ((...) and b.account_number='12345678')
```

where you probably want it to be

```
WHERE (left(b.loc_id,1)=left(a.table_name,1) OR (...))
and b.account_number='12345678'
```

Use parentheses as shown to fix this.

Comment: So the last part of my code nullified the entire "and/or" portion of the command because the I broke the chain?

Comment: Well, you thought it would add a condition to the whole `WHERE` clause, but it only added a condition to the part after `OR`, because without parentheses the ANDs have precedence over the ORs. So the additional condition didn't "nullify" the whole `WHERE` clause; only it didn't affect the result rows you got with the part before `OR`.